# phantomjs unable to find element on page

Tags: r, phantomjs, rselenium

Recently, I've been having trouble driving phantomjs under RSelenium. It seems that the browser is unable to locate anything on the page using `findElement()`. If I pass something as simple as:

```
library("RSelenium")
RSelenium::checkForServer()
RSelenium::startServer()
rd <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs")
rd$open()
Sys.sleep(5)

rd$navigate("https://www.Facebook.com")
searchBar <- rd$findElement(using = "id", "email")
```

I get the error below:

```
Error:   Summary: NoSuchElement
Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
class: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
```

Any thoughts on what is causing this? It doesn't seem to matter what page I navigate to; it simply fails anytime I try to locate an element on the webpage. This issue started recently and I noticed it when my cron jobs began failing.

I'm working in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with R 3.3.1 and phantomjs 2.1.1. I don't suspect some  type of compatibility issue as this has worked very recently and I haven't updated anything.

Comment: Google was a simple working example. It R throws an error regardless of the site. I can update the question to exclude Google but that seems irrelevant

Comment: Apologies if you got that impression. I was never actually scraping Google for content, and was unaware of the violation. Question updated to exclude Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of `phantomjs` you installed may be limited. See [here](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/p/phantomjs/phantomjs_2.1.1+dfsg-2/changelog)

> - Disabled Ghostdriver due to pre-built source-less Selenium blobs.
> - Added README.Debian explaining differences from upstream "phantomjs".

If you installed recently using `apt-get` then this is most likely the case. You can download from the [phantomjs website](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) and place the bin location in your PATH.

Alternatively use `npm` to install a version for you

```
npm install phantomjs-prebuilt
```

This will then but a link to the bin in `node_modules/.bin/phantomjs`.

For the reasons behind the limitations in apt-get you can read the README.Debian file contained [here](http://http.debian.net/debian/pool/main/p/phantomjs/phantomjs_2.1.1+dfsg-2.debian.tar.xz).

> ### Limitations
>
> Unlike original "phantomjs" binary that is statically linked with
>   modified QT+WebKit, Debian package is built with system libqt5webkit5.
>   Unfortunately the latter do not have webSecurity extensions therefore
>   "--web-security=no" is expected to fail.
>
> https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13727#issuecomment-155609276
>
> ---
>
> Ghostdriver is crippled due to removed source-less pre-built blobs:
>
> src/ghostdriver/third_party/webdriver-atoms/*
>
> Therefore all PDF functionality is broken.
>
> ---
>
> PhantomJS cannot run in headless mode (if there is no X server
>   available).
>
> Unfortunately it can not be fixed in Debian. To achieve headless-ness
>   upstream statically link with customised QT + Webkit. We don't want to
>   ship forks of those projects. It would be great to eventually convince
>   upstream to use standard libraries. Meanwhile one can use "xvfb-run"
>   from "xvfb" package:
>
> ```
> xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0 640x480x16" phantomjs
> ```

If you don't want to set your path for phantomjs then you can add it as a extra:

```
library(RSelenium)

selServ <- startServer()
pBin <- list(phantomjs.binary.path = "/home/john/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs")
rd <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs"
                   , extraCapabilities = pBin)
Sys.sleep(5)
rd$open()

rd$navigate("https://www.Facebook.com")
searchBar <- rd$findElement(using = "id", "email")

rd$close()
selServ$stop()
```

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. Seems like I recall reading about this. What throws me is that it has always worked in the past and I don't recall updating anything. All the same, this seems like a good starting point and I'll look into it later today and report back.

Comment: Top stuff. Added some info on starting phantomjs when bin is not in PATH.

Comment: Well, it did seem to be an issue with the `phantomjs` version. Like I said, my  jobs had not failed until rather recently, so perhaps I ran an `apt-get upgrade` or `apt-get dist-upgrade` at some point. I'll have to be more careful with that moving forward. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ander2ed good to hear. If you are interested in headless browsers you may find firefox/chrome ran from a docker container to be of use. There is a vignette detailing the basics at http://rpubs.com/johndharrison/RSelenium-Docker